# Annyang does not playSound in page for mobile

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile, voice

I am trying to make a page that responds to voice commands and I am testing it in my mobile (samsung GT-S7390).

I am using Tal Ater´s excellent "annyang" script and it works *almost* perfectly.

But there is a puzzling behaviour for which I am asking for help.

When you open the page and click on the button "Activate10b", 3 simple functions are executed: playSound, showStuff and animate.

However, when you try to execute the same 3 functions through Annyang, only 2 work (showStuff and animate), but playSound does not.

Even more intriguing, the page pops a javascript Alert saying that the audio has played (but there is no sound).

I have even tried a workaround by making Annyang CLICK the button (as you can see in the page´s code below) but the result is the same. Apparently, the button IS clicked, and playSound IS executed (hence the alert) but the mobile "knows" the command came from Annyang (or not through touchscreen clicking) and does not play the sound.

Could any of you help me in this? But please keep in mind I am only a humble beginner, so your answer has to be adequate for the "javascript for dummies" level... ;)

Thank you a lot in advance for your attention!

====PAGE CODE (COMPLETE)=====

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HTML lang=en>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>ANNYANG TEST FOR MOBILE</TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2900.2055" name=GENERATOR>
<META name="robots" content="all,index,follow" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.4.0/annyang.min.js">
</script>
```

```
<script>
function playSound ( soundname )
  {
    var thissound = document.getElementById( soundname );
    thissound.play();
    alert( "Played " + soundname );
  }
</script>
```

```
<audio id="audio1" source src="beep1.wav" preload="auto" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

```
<script>function showStuff(id){document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';}
</script>

<script>function hideStuff(id){document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';}
</script>
```

```
<script>
    if (annyang) {

    var commands = {'good': function() 

      {$('#tpsreport').animate({top: '10px'}); $('#fala').trigger('click');}   

      };

    annyang.start();

      }

</script>

<style>
.div1{position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px; height:220px; width: 95%; border: 3px groove purple; background-color: pink;}
.div2{position: absolute; top: 230px; left: 10px; height:1500px; width: 95%; border: 3px groove purple;}
.div3{display:none; position: absolute; top: 260px; left: 300px; height:200px; width: 300px; border: 3px groove purple; background-color: orange;}
.div4{position: absolute; top: 860px; left: 30px; height:200px; width: 300px; border: 3px groove purple; background-color: red;} 
</style>


</head>

<!---BODY---------------------------------------------->
<body onload="annyang.start()" style="background-color: white; scrollbar: no; scrollbars: no; scrolling: no; overflow-x: hidden;"/>


<span id="dummy"></span>



<DIV class="div1"/>
</DIV>


<DIV class="div2"/>
     <input id="fala" type="button" onclick="playSound('audio1'); showStuff('lulu'); $('#tpsreport').animate

({top:'10px'});" value="Activate 10b!" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; cursor: pointer; width: 200px; 

height: 70px; background-color: #6080dd; border: none; color: white; font-size: 30px;">
</DIV>



<DIV class="div3" id="lulu"/>
LULU
</DIV>



<DIV class="div4" id="tpsreport"/>
GOOD MORNING
</DIV>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You need to edit your code down to the relevant parts (you can remove the `<style>` section, for example), and make sure you format it using the form tools provided. We can help better if we can understand what we're looking at.

Comment: You are ABSOLUTELY right, Andy, thank you. Sorry it came out so garbled, I am unfamiliar with the formatting options. I am trying to format it adequately and as soon as I have I shall re-post it adequately.

Comment: If you want some help drop everything into a jsfiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, it looks a bit better now I hope....actually it is all in one piece, just one long text (.htm extension) file. And yes, I would love any help, Andy, but I don´t know how to make a "jsfiddle"...rs.

Comment: Ok, Andy , I have edited the file yet once again, hope it is clearer now? It is only one txt file with .htm extension, so if you copy it with notepad and change the extension you can see what it does. Again, thanks for any comments. ;)